# Use optional index with ArrayList - is it possible?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, collections, android-arrayadapter

I am new in Android and Java developing...so maybe my question will be confused or not normal :)
Is it possible to make an ArrayList or any collection where I give the index value?

Example:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(3, "Item1");
list.add(10, "Item2");
```

When I try to use this I got an exception message: IndexOutOfBounds...
I want to add my ArrayList (collection) to an Android ArrayAdapter...

So! Is it possible to make a collection with optional index and it is able to add android ArrayAdapter?

Thanks the help!

Comment: Why you would like to add by index and not in order which you add elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HashMap, it should solve your problem
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Answer (score 2):

You can add an element to a specific location in the ArrayList, but only if the size of the ArrayList prior to that operation is higher or equal to the index you are specifying. This means that the ArrayList can have no gaps. You can't add an elements to the index number 3 if indices 0,1,2 are not already occupied.

So, `list.size()` should be at least 3 in order for `list.add(3, "Item1");` to be valid. Adding elements to the ArrayList in this manner increments the index of all the elements of the list starting in the given index.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own List implementation which will support this functionality:

```
public class SparseArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {

    @Override
    public E set(int index, E element) {
        while (size() <= index) add(null);
        return super.set(index, element);
    }

}
```